# Why are there two headers within a jpg file?

Tags: python, header, hex, photoshop, jpeg

I've been working with Python to create an image viewer:

I noticed that when I was working with one of the files that it had two headers? Or at least two occurrences of JFIF, which I thought was unusual. Is there any particular reason that the file is structured like this?

Here is a sample of the file:

[image]

See lines starting offset 0 and 812

Comment: Those are different info fields

Comment: Okay. Could you expand on your comment please?

Comment: Your file probably contains two images, a thumbnail and the full-size image. I'm not as up on JPEG formatting as I used to be so I can't expand this into an answer. You can find a quick description of the headers in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a [thumbnail resource](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/PhotoshopFileFormats.htm#50577409_74450), judging from its ID being `0x040C`. To find the ID, look at the line with `8BIM...New Win` and read about: [image resource blocks](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/PhotoshopFileFormats.htm#50577409_pgfId-1037685) and [image resource IDs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/PhotoshopFileFormats.htm#50577409_38034).